# sqlite improve query speed

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

I have an sqlite query that is dynamically generated like:

```
SELECT * FROM gsmr_data WHERE test_id='86' AND device='devicename' AND id<4371808 AND (metric='C2' OR metric='C2_N1' OR metric='C2_N2' OR metric='C2_N3' OR metric='C2_N4' OR metric='C2_N5' OR metric='C2_N6') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500
```

Where id is based on the last result and the metric (in the OR part) are added dynamically.

My table looks like:

[image]

And I have the following indexes in the table:

[image]

The query takes long (7 seconds in sqlite db browser)

Is there anything else that I can do to improve the speed of the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're testing a bunch of columns, but your indexes are for only one column apiece, so only one of them will be used (See [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output to see which one; running [ANALYZE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) might change which one the query planner uses).

Using a multi-column index could allow for better performance by limiting the overall number of rows looked at (But of course, like all indexes, comes at a cost of increased time inserting, deleting, and updating rows, and taking up more space).

I'd look first at adding an index on all the columns used in the `WHERE`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_gsmr_data ON gsmr_data(test_id, device, metric, id)
```

See the [query optimizer documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) for why `id` is the last one in the index. Also see the sqlite3 shell's [.expert command](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#index_recommendations_sqlite_expert_) for suggesting indexes for queries, and an [overview of how sqlite uses indexes](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
SELECT * FROM gsmr_data
WHERE test_id='86' AND device='devicename' AND id<4371808 AND
   metric in('C2', 'C2_N1', 'C2_N2', 'C2_N3', 'C2_N4', 'C2_N5', 'C2_N6')
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500
```